# Change multiple divs of same id to different heights

Tags: javascript, html

So I have multiple divs with the same id 'stick'. I want to iterate through all these elements and give each a random height. here is what I tried:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        for(var i = 0; i < 47; i++) {
            var rand = 200;
            document.getElementsById('stick')[i].style.height= rand+'px';  
        }
    </script>
```

This code doesn't work sadly. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not add same id for more than one element.
Use class names. And `document.getElemetsById` is not a defined function, only `document.getElementById` (without "s") that should return one element.

HTML:

```
    <div class="stick"> </div>
    <div class="stick"> </div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('stick');
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var rand = 200 * Math.random();
        divs[i].style.height= rand+'px';  
    }
</script>
```

This may works. But I recommend to use jQuery framework, for JavaScript coding, because these lines become a simpler code in jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('.stick').each(function(){            //iterates all elements having stick class
         $(this).height(200 * Math.random());       //inside the callback the 'this' is the current html element. etc ...
     });
</script>
```

jQuery homepage: http://jquery.com/

Fast including to your website, just import the jQuery from CDN url, inside the head:

```
   <head>
       ...
       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

ID's should be completely unique within the document. Change your ID's to unique values, and you can reference them individually. If you wish to act on a collection of elements, use the `class` tag to link them together. To read up on `CSS Classes` you can look at [this documentation](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/class.php). This will help you understand the purpose of classes in HTML and CSS.

**Your problem**

`getElementsByID()` doesn't work. `getElementByID()` is the correct syntax.

So

```
document.getElementsById('stick')[i].style.height= rand+'px';
```

Will become

```
document.getElementById('stick')[i].style.height= rand+'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple elements with the same `id`. `id` must be *unique*. You need to use `class` and retrieve your elements using class name. You could use jquery to assist you: `var elements = $('.stick')`